# Primefaces InputText does not work after validation failed

Tags: validation, primefaces, dialog

I have a table and each row has a delete button. After clicking on delete button, a confirm dialog should appear. In this dialog, there is only one required input field and a cancel and delete button. If the filed is filled, everything is ok, but if it will be left blank, the field will be red highlighted with a message under it, that the user should enter a value. At this moment, if I want to enter a value, I can not do it. Only if I close the dialog and click on the delete button again, the dialog comes again with the field still highlighted and I am able to enter a value. Why isn't it possible to enter a value directly after validation?

I have seen several problems here regarding updating an inputText field after validation failed, but I think I have another problem.

xhtml:

```
<h:form id="dialogForm"> ...

    <p:inputText id="comment" value="#{myController.comment}" maxlength="14" required="true" placeholder="please enter a comment"/>
     <p:message for="comment"/> ...

                <p:commandButton value="#{message.delete}"
                                 action="#{myController.doDelete()}"
                                 process="@form"
                                 update="@form"
                                 oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){ 
                                 PF('dialog').hide();}"/> ...
</h:form>
```

Comment: What does 'I cannot do it mean' no focus? No submit? WW-III?

Comment: I can not enter a value in the field as if the inputText is disabled.